# hulls of non-closed prime ideals

Tags: banach-algebras

If P is a closed prime ideal in a commutative unital complex Banach algebra, then the hull of P is **connected** (an easy consequence of Shilov's idempotent theorem)  Is the same true for non-closed prime ideals?

Comment: Can I assume the algebra is semisimple? (Also, I assume you are referring to the hull-kernel topology)

Comment: I just edited the post;  meant of course connected.  One may restrict to the semi-simple case.

Comment: @ Yemon Choi No, I refer to the Gelfand topology, the natural one which makes the maximal ideal space a compact Hausdorff space.